# Server slow, but plenty of CPU & RAM

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, traffic, high-load, traffic-management

My site has gone from getting 20,000 visits/day, to 182,000 yesterday, due to being featured on a number of popular sites.

The site has become somewhat unresponsive. Many requests will lead to a timeout. Yet there is plenty of CPU & RAM available. CPU and RAM does has not really peaked above 20%, and is on average around 12%.

When trying to download the homepage with WGET, it will stall here:

Resolving domain.io (domain.io)... 91.121.220.92
Connecting to domain.io (domain.io)|91.121.220.92|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

But if it does actually connect, it will download the page quickly. Additionally, I can connect to phpMyAdmin via the brower via IP and it works as normal.

This leads me to believe there is an issue in Apache

My settings:

```
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
StartServers          5
MinSpareServers       5
MaxSpareServers      10
MaxClients          150
MaxRequestsPerChild   0

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
StartServers          2
MinSpareThreads      25
MaxSpareThreads      75
ThreadLimit          64
ThreadsPerChild      25
MaxClients          150
MaxRequestsPerChild   0

<IfModule mpm_event_module>
StartServers          2
MinSpareThreads      25
MaxSpareThreads      75
ThreadLimit          64
ThreadsPerChild      25
MaxClients          150
MaxRequestsPerChild   0
```

Not which sure of these I am using, will check now.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what to tinker with here? In Apache or otherwise.

When I login via SSH it says:

```
System load:    2.92
Processes:           289
Users logged in:     0
Memory usage:   9%
Swap usage:     0%
```

The server is a 4 core 3.2Ghz with 32GB RAM and 2x2TB, little of which is used.

Answer (score 1):

You should enable `mod_status` and see if you're not reaching apache limits of concurrent connections. Probably you have set this limits too low and should increase values of `MaxClients`, `ThreadLimit` and `ThreadPerChild` depends on which mpm module you are using.

Comment: I have checked and it is prefork.

I have disabled KeepAlive and upped MaxClients to 300 and it is working better. I will try your suggestions now...

Comment: mod_status will show you how many preforked childs are busy and how many is idle, waiting for new clients. AFAIK apache can handle only MaxClients concurent connections.

Answer (score 1):

Some other stuff to check, on apache's error log, chek for entries like this one:

```
apache server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting
```

That means you've reached the configured maximum number of processes / threads

Another good indication that apache isn't keeping up with load, perhaps because of the max thread / process configuration is an overflow if the listen queue, you can check it like this:

```
netstat -s | grep -i listen
```

Normally you wont get output from that, but in case of trouble you get:

```
# netstat -s | grep -i listen 
    26760 times the listen queue of a socket overflowed
    26760 SYNs to LISTEN sockets ignored
#
```

Hope this helps